# Write a program (or algorithm) in python which breaks up a string of texts into even and odd characters

Tags: python

```
def breakString(str):
    i = 0
    even = []
    odd = []
    for char in str
        if (i%2==0)
            even.push(char)
        else
            odd.push(char)
```

For some reason, this is not running in my python.

Comment: What are you waiting for? Write it!

Answer (score 0):

- dont use "str" as a variable name, it has a reserved meaning in python.
- end your clauses with colons before you indent.
- use append instead of push.
- you're not counting i, it's always 0

With that in mind you end up with, e.g.:

```
even = []
odd = []
def breakString(st): 
    for char in st:
        i = st.count(char)
        if (i%2==0):
            even.append(char)
        else:
            odd.append(char)   

breakString("aba noun")

print even
print odd
```

output:

```
['a', 'a', 'n', 'n']
['b', ' ', 'o', 'u']
```

you're told of your syntactical errors by your compiler. So next time, take some effort into analyzing what it tells you.

Comment: Gladly. Consider accepting the answer if it was helpful (next to the vote counter).

Answer (score 0):

The main reason it isn't working is that you aren't incrementing `i`. You also aren't returning anything. You can read up on for loops here [on the python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop). A working method could look like the following:

```
def breakString(s):
even = []
odd = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    if (i % 2 == 0):
        even.append(s[i])
    else:
        odd.append(s[i])
return [even, odd]
```

I'm returning as an array of an array, but you could do whatever.